# How to check my system is locked or not using c#?

Tags: c#

I am creating C# window application, by this I want to know system status (locked or not or sleep) by running it at random time.
Below code will not work because I am running my exe at random time and then close it, So it can't catch below event code. Can someone help me how can I check windows status in my case?

```
private const int SessionLockParam = 0x7;
private const int SessionUnlockParam = 0x8;
```

Comment: Add the rest of the code

Comment: I have override inbuitl method, and this is detecting system message and it is working when system is locking because it is running and able to chatch the message, but I want to check at random time because my exe will not run continusly, protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {

            if (m.Msg == SessionChangeMessage || m.Msg == 798)
            {
               //Dosomthing
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }